# Getting Undefined stored into array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to run the following code[image]

I would like to store the contents of the log file into user defined array. How can I do that. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: `console.log()` just prints things, it doesn't return the value, so it doesn't make sense to use it in an assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

console.log(); has no return type, split the statement in your loop into 2 statements.

```
console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
price[i] = elements[i].innerHTML;
```